# Trying to create a left hand riemann sum calculation using functions in C

Tags: c

When I run the code it does not prompt for user input. I am not sure what to do.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
float rieman(float lower, float upper, float intervals);
float rieman(float lower, float upper, float intervals) {

    float width = (upper - lower) / intervals;
    float result=0;
    for (float i = lower; i < upper; i+=width) {
       result +=  exp(pow(i, 2));
    }
    return result*width;
}

int main() {
    float upper;
    float lower;
    float intervals;
    scanf("%f", &lower);
    scanf("%f", &upper);
    scanf("%f", &intervals);
    printf("%f", rieman(lower, upper, intervals));
}
```

I tried changing the incrment counter on the for loop and this did not change anything. I also tried changing some values from floats to ints and this did not help.

Comment: Did you type the 3 numbers in that the program expects but does not prompt for? That may confuse you into thinking nothing happens because it's waiting for input.

Comment: Probably pointless... Is it possible this is just floating point accuracy? I'm unfamiliar with Riemenn Sums

Comment: Re “When I run the code nothing happens”: Did you type any input for the program? Your program does not print any prompt; it just waits for input. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of the input you gave the program.

Comment: @jonston68 Why are you using `float` variables with `double` functions?  Makes most sense here to use `double` variables with the `double` functions.

Comment: @jonston68 Post the _exact_ input used.

Comment: it does not prompt for input.

Comment: What prompt do you expect to appear and why?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the program, it requests input. It does not print a prompt. The normal behavior of the program is for the terminal to sit, waiting for you to type something.

After running the program, type three numbers, separated by spaces or by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After entering all three numbers, press <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.